# c# - Problem calling public void from class

Tags: c#

When I Call the public void inside My form, where my public form is declared, It works fine. But when i call it from another class, it doesnt work..?
I have done like so in my class.

```
otherForm oForm = new otherForm();
oForm.thisvoid();
```

In the public void, I'm loading a Url in my webView. And as I said before, calling it from my Form, where it is declared, it works. So there can't really be something wrong with the function in itself.

This is my public void

```
public void thisvoid()
    {
        try
        {
            webview.LoadUrl("http://localhost:5000);
        } catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            Console.WriteLine(ee);
        }
    }
```

The error is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

Comment: By "it does not work" do you mean "does not compile" or "does not display form and the like"?

Comment: The function does not work, as it is supposed to, but it DOES work as it's supposed to, when i call it from the form, where it is declared.

Comment: is webview object properly created in the constructor?

Comment: Does it write anything to the console? (In catch block)

Comment: @GrayCat Yes it does.

Comment: But what does it write? Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Comment: right now: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: So the problem occurs at `webview.LoadUrl("http://localhost:5000);` check your webview object.

Comment: I kinda figured that out. But there is not a problem when i just call it in my FOrm1 where it is declared, so it must be a problem with connecting it together

Comment: You have initialized the webview somewhere else in the Form1. This initialization is not called if you create the object somewhere else (outside this form). Initialize the object in your thisvoid method or in the object constructor.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because you are invoking it from another thread.

Comment: @Dave Could you give an example?

Comment: in the "thisvoid" method, point the "webview" to its location before you use it, for example webview = new WebView();. This is very basic stuff and if you don't know about it, please read more about the OOP.

Comment: i already have that..? the WebView webview = new WebView();

Comment: Yes, but you don't have it in the thisvoid method or the class constructor. So when you invoke the method from "somewhere else", the webview == null.

Comment: Ahh, so, where should i put "object webview" ?, in the form where i declared my public void, the webview is in that form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

According to what you wrote in comments `webview` object is not initialized in constructor. Add its initialization to constructor of `otherForm` and it should work.

My guess as to why it works when you call it from within `otherForm` is that you initialize it somewhere along the way.

EXAMPLE (EDIT):

When you instantiate your `otherForm` with a `new` keyword from other class e.g

```
var oF = new otherForm();
```

what runtime does it searches for parameterless constructor that is special method of a class that is executed upon creation of class instance. It should be named as a class.

Now the second part - the `webview` you use is an object - be it control, other form or just some object. It is stored a field of your class. But, unless you create an instance of it, it is `null` - meaning that this object does not exist, you only have its potential handle. So you have to create this object like this (class names are completely made up):

```
public class otherForm
{
    WebView webview;       

    public otherForm()
    {
        webview = new WebView();
    }
}
```

Of course, the WebView constructor itself might require more parameters that you would need to provide.

So what happens here is:

1. Runtime encounters `var otherForm = new otherForm();`
2. It searches for (in this case) parameterless constructor
3. It executes statements in the constructor
4. Among those there is creation of `webview` object
5. When it later calls `webView` in any method on that instance the object exists and can be used.

What you missed probably was point number 4. Example of how to include it can be found above.

More reads:

[Stack Overflow on NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

[Some examples of constructors](https://www.dotnetperls.com/constructor)

Comment: could u give an example? im not qure sure i get what you're saying.